# "Sparse" Overflow error in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

I want to evalutate an integral
$$I = \int_{-0.01}^0 \int_{-0.01}^0 \left(\frac{1}{\sinh|t_2+t_1+T| \sinh|t_2+t_1|}\right)^{2/m} \left(\frac{\sinh|2t_1+t_2+T|}{\sinh|t_1+T|}\right)^{1/m} \left(\frac{\sinh|t_2|}{\sinh|t_1|}\right)^{1/m},$$
where $m=3$ is fixed and I want to vary $T$. This integral is mathematically shown to be convergent. For various values of $T$ within range $10^{-6}<T<10^{-4}$, I sometimes get an overflow error, such as:

```
NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand ((Csch[Abs[t1]] Sinh[Abs[t2]])^(1/3) (Csch[Abs[5.01187*10^-6+t1]] Sinh[Abs[<<22>>+2 t1+t2]])^(1/3))/(Sinh[Abs[t1+t2]] Sinh[Abs[5.01187*10^-6+t1+t2]])^(2/3) has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1},{0.,2.48466*10^-32}}.
```

I don't know a particular pattern for what values of $T$ does this error occurs. (However, the error does not occur for $|T|>0.1$.) Below is my relevant code:

```
exp1 = (Csch[Abs[t1]] Sinh[Abs[t2]])^(1/
  m) (Sinh[Abs[t1 + t2]] Sinh[Abs[T + t1 + t2]])^(-2/
   m) (Csch[Abs[T + t1]] Sinh[Abs[T + 2 t1 + t2]])^(1/m)
tab1 = Table[{T, 
   NIntegrate[exp1 /. {m -> 3}, {t1, -0.01, 0}, {t2, -0.01, 0}]}, {T, 
   Table[10^(-n), {n, 4, 6, 0.1}]}]
```

The result is:

```
{{0.0001, 0.225753 - 2.69464*10^-8 I}, {0.0000794328, 
  0.225296 - 2.4616*10^-8 I}, {0.0000630957, 
  0.224902 - 2.37137*10^-8 I}, {0.0000501187, 
  0.224563}, {0.0000398107, 0.22427}, {0.0000316228, 
  0.224019}, {0.0000251189, 0.223802}, {0.0000199526, 
  0.223616 - 3.04706*10^-8 I}, {0.0000158489, 
  0.223455}, {0.0000125893, 0.223317}, {0.00001, 
  0.223199}, {7.94328*10^-6, 0.223097}, {6.30957*10^-6, 
  0.223009}, {5.01187*10^-6, 
  NIntegrate[
   exp1 /. {m -> 3}, {t1, -0.01, 0}, {t2, -0.01, 0}]}, {3.98107*10^-6,
   NIntegrate[
   exp1 /. {m -> 3}, {t1, -0.01, 0}, {t2, -0.01, 0}]}, {3.16228*10^-6,
   0.222814}, {2.51189*10^-6, 0.222766}, {1.99526*10^-6, 
  0.222725}, {1.58489*10^-6, 0.22269}, {1.25893*10^-6, 
  0.22266}, {1.*10^-6, 0.222634}}
```

Note that sometimes the integral is left unevaluated.

Why does this error happen? Note that for $T<0$, the only singularity of the integral is at $t_1=0$, which is the boundary of the integration range.

Comment: Independant of the value `T` there is a singularity at `t1=t2=0`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann But that is again the boundary (corner) of the integration range!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica v12.2(Windows 10) doesn't show this  behavior.

Try with rationalized integration limits

```
tab1 = Table[{T, 
NIntegrate[exp1 /. {m -> 3}, {t1, -1/100, 0}, {t2, -1/100, 0}]}, {T,Table[10^(-n), {n, Range[4,8]}]}]
(*{{1/10000, 0.000109877}, {1/100000, 0.000109843}, {1/1000000,0.000109839}, {1/10000000, 0.000109838}, {1/100000000, 0.000109838}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks! That is very interesting, and I wonder why using exact numbers help in this case.

Comment: You're welcome. Before starting evaluation of a command, Mathematica often tries to simplifiy the expression. Numeric numbers possible leads to roundoff effects.

Comment: Exact numbers have `infinite` precision.